# Spring: No matching bean found which qualifies as autowire

Tags: java, spring

Application-Context is correctly setup!

Heres my class scenario

```
public interface IManager
{
 public void doStuff();
}

@Component
public abstract class ManagerAction implements IManager
{
  @Async
  @Override
  public void doStuff()
  {
     //doing stuff
  }

  public abstract manageWorker();
}

@Component
public class Working extends ManagerAction
{
  @Override
  public manageWorker()
  {
    //some busy code
  }
}

@Component
public class NotWorking extends ManagerAction
{
  @Override
  public manageWorker()
  {
    //some busy code
  }
}

@Service
public class BusinessWorker
{
  @Autowire
  private IManager manager_;

  public void preformTasks()
  {    
    manager_.doStuff();
  }
}
```

**Heres my error**

```
ERROR [main] (ContextLoader.java:307) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BusinessWorker': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.B
eanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.background.IManager com.background.BusinessWorker.manager_; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.
factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.background.IManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
 this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.background.IManager com.background.BusinessWorker.manager_; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.background.IManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 
bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 28 more
```

Application-Context

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<task:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.background" />
```

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with your annotations - have you ensured that your component scan covers all the packages correctly, especially the one containing `Working` class

Comment: @BijuKunjummen see edit at bottom

Comment: Oh, okay, do you also have multiple context files - one defined through DispatcherServlet and one through ContextLoaderListener in web.xml..can you check this also please.

Comment: @stackoverflow is this the root (last) exception? Because as Biju said your annotations look right.

Comment: @mkhelif the root cause is Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.background.IQManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2
: [Working, NotWorking]

Comment: @mkhelif I left one class out. So I have an interface that gets implemented by ManagerAction and ManagerAction has two extending classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says it all: you try to autowire an instance of IManager, but two different Spring components implement this interface, so Spring doesn't know which one to autowire. You need to [use the @Qualifier annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) to specify which one you want Spring to autowire.

Comment: But I will essentially need both extended classes at some point during execution. How do I tell spring to use the appropriate polymorphic type?

Comment: Then autowire them both, using two different fields, each having the appropriate Qualifier. Spring can't initialize one variable with two objects.

Comment: One more observation I saw if you using  @Async annotation in your service implementation class and trying to auto wire the service implementation class, spring is not able to auto wire it. In that case you have to auto wire your interface class not the implementation class and that solves the problem